# sails:how to convert array to json object

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, csv

I'm trying to read .csv file using `fast-csv` node module.If i read that file means it will return array of data like given below

```
[ 'Vehicle', 'Date', 'Location', 'Speed' ]
[ 'BMW',
  '30, Jul 2013 09:24 AM',
  'Hauz Khas, Enclave, New Delhi, Delhi, India',
  '42' ]
[ 'Honda CBR',
  '30, Jul 2013 12:00 AM',
  'Military Road,  West Bengal 734013,  India',
  '0' ]
```

I want to convert that into json object like key value pairs.i'm trying below snippet to read csv file

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");
csv.fromPath(uploadedFiles[0].fd)
        .on("data", function(rows){
               console.log(rows);
        });
```

how can i convert this into json.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

clearly rows[0] is your key map :

```
var keyMap   = []; 
var jsonRows = []; 

for(var i in rows) 
 {
   if(i === 0) 
    {
      keyMap = rows[i]; //save your keys
    }
   else
    {
      var row = rows[i];  //get the current record
      var obj = {}; 
      for(var r in row)
       {
          obj[keyMap[r]] = row[r];  //add each value of current record with its corresponding mapped key
       }
      jsonRows.push(obj); 
    }
 }

 console.log(jsonRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use headers option :

```js
var csv = require("fast-csv");
csv.fromPath(uploadedFiles[0].fd, {headers : true})
        .on("data", function(data){
               console.log(data);
        });
```

You can also specify headers :

```js
var csv = require("fast-csv");
csv.fromPath(uploadedFiles[0].fd,{ headers : [ 'Vehicle', 'Date', 'Location', 'Speed' ]})
        .on("data", function(data){
               console.log(data);
        });
```

Comment: Use first one. Set headers true.